# CSS Media Queries Not Working?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to hide some divs for people that are using >800px resolution width.

I put this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 799px) {
.well {
  display: hidden;
    } 
}
```

In my stylesheet, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using >800px** so if a screen is bigger, then **I'm trying to hide some `div`s**

Your query is wrong then:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 799px) {
.well {
  display: hidden;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sheesh, that's embarrassing. The css in the site does has min-device (not max), I just typed it wrong here. I'm using bootstrap, so I'm putting it in the bootstrap.css file. Do I need to put it in all of the .css files? (bootstrap-responsive.css, bootstrap.min.css, etc)?

Comment: bootstrap handles does thing, no need to do it again. but you can conditional add some more media query for your own suits, en than do like in the proposed code. check if the "well" is "on" in this media view